# Interface "League\Config\ConfigurationProviderInterface" not found - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set the email verification for my Laravel App, but I get this message when I register a user: `Interface "League\Config\ConfigurationProviderInterface" not found`. I didn't found any same thread about that anywhere else.

The line of code that cause problem is this one: `event(new Registered($user)); //Send email verif` in my `RegisteredUserController.php`. All the auth files and stuff were generate with the Laravel Ui starter pack. My Laravel version is 9. Does anyone have a clue? Thank you!

Here's the `RegisteredUserController.php` code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Http\Controllers\UtilityController;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('frontend.auth.register', ['towns' => UtilityController::GetTowns()]);
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(RegisterRequest $request)
    {   
        $user = User::create([
            'firstname' => $request->firstname,
            'lastname' => $request->lastname,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'city' => $request->town,
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user)); //Send email verif

        return;

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with("register", true);
    }
}
```

The `User.php` modal:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Prunable;

use App\Models\Favorite;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes, Prunable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'password',
        'city',
        'role'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: The error message will show you what code is causing the problem. It sounds like you haven't installed things properly. Have you run `composer install`?

Comment: Yes I already did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by simply delete the `league` folder vendor and re-upload it to my server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).